# Identify DB changes automatically in spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I have requirement that if any changes in the db column automatically the java code should get the updated data from the db column without restarting the application server.

I am using Spring Boot, Hibernate, Oracle Db, Tomcat Server.

Please share if any inputs

Comment: This sounds like a java question, so I've added the `java` tag

Comment: Well, don't cache the data in your Java code, and query the database whenever you need it, and you'll have what you want. That's what a DB is all about.

Comment: What's the problem with pooling data every few seconds for new updates?

Answer (score 0):

With an Oracle database you could use some Java in a database trigger - more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.html).

Naturally, there are a couple of consideration here.  Firstly, note that this Java is running in the built-in JVM in Oracle, so you would need to send a hint across to the Tomcat JVM.  Also this route would have a scalability limit - it wouldn't suit a particularly high rate of updates.